# Link error with geometry shader (driver bug?)

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

I have a GLSL program that works on some machines, but fails to link on on one particular machine.  I suspect a driver bug, but hope that someone will recognize something I'm doing as being poorly supported, and suggest an alternative.

If I omit the geometry shader, the vertex and fragment shaders link successfully.

The error log after the link error says:

```
Vertex shader(s) failed to link, fragment shader(s) failed to link, geometry shader(s) failed to link.
ERROR: error(#275) Symbol 'gl_AtiVertexData' is defined with 2 different types between two stages
ERROR: error(#275) Symbol 'gl_AtiVertexData' is defined with 2 different types between two stages
ERROR: error(#275) Symbol 'gl_AtiVertexData' is defined with 2 different types between two stages
```

My code does not contain the symbol `gl_AtiVertexData`, and Google finds no hits for it.

The `GL_RENDERER` string is "ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4670", `GL_VERSION` is "3.3.11672 Compatibility Profile Context", and `GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION` is 3.30.

I've trimmed down my shader programs as much as possible, so that they no longer pretend to do anything useful, but still reproduce the problem.

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330
in vec4 quesaVertex;
out VertexData {
    vec4 interpolatedColor;
};
void main()
{
    gl_Position = quesaVertex;
    interpolatedColor = vec4(1.0);
}
```

Geometry shader:

```
#version 330
layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices=3) out;

in VertexData {
    vec4 interpolatedColor;
} gs_in[];
out VertexData {
    vec4 interpolatedColor;
} gs_out;

void main() {
    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    gs_out.interpolatedColor = gs_in[0].interpolatedColor;
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    gs_out.interpolatedColor = gs_in[1].interpolatedColor;
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    gs_out.interpolatedColor = gs_in[2].interpolatedColor;
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330
in VertexData {
    vec4 interpolatedColor;
};
out vec4 fragColor;

void main()
{
    fragColor = interpolatedColor;
}
```

---

Later information:

When I tried renaming the interface block `VertexData` to `IBlock`, then the error message talked about a symbol `gl_AtiIBlock` instead of `gl_AtiVertexData`, so that symbol name was a red herring.

If I don't use interface blocks, then the program links correctly.  That's a bother, because I'll need to write the vertex or fragment shader differently depending on whether there is a geometry shader between the vertex and fragment shaders, but maybe that's what I need to do.

Comment: Where do you declare the type for `VertexData`? If you want a structure then use `struct` before `VertexData`. Because you say these are "trimed" shaders, I suppose you have a good reason to use structures instead of plain/arrays `in/out` vars.

Comment: @Ripi2: "*Where do you declare the type for VertexData?*" It's an interface block, not a struct. It's a standard GLSL named construct.

Comment: Have you tried not using interface blocks where possible?

Comment: @Andrea: thanks for the idea, it does work without interface blocks.  I added information about that to the question.

Comment: Anything change if you request a Core context?

Comment: @genpfault, same thing happens with a 3.3 or 3.2 core profile context.